# Create telnet client that uses server's TCP/IP stack instead of users?

Tags: php, telnet

If I used something server side like PHP inconjuction with some web wizardry for the interface, would it be possible to create a web-based telnet client that uses the server's TCP/IP stack instead of the users?

I've seen a PHP based MUD client, but it uses Websockets or Flash based on the user's machine. I'm looking to see if it would be possible to make use of the server's connection to generate a telnet session.

At work, telnet is blocked outbound. I would login to a web server that had this little web app running, and through that web server, I could utilize it's ability to telnet to another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but if it would be using HTTP, which is [stateless](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), you would have a lot of overhead (like logging in each request).

Since it is telnet though, its fairly simple. Check out [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php). There's a few telnet examples in the comment section.